# Facebook Graph API - permanent user access token for app (not page)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a user access token for our App that expires in 60 days, but we have about 30 pages under this App. I know there is a way to create a permanent token for each Page, but is there a way to create a permanent token for the App?

Also I know I can generate an App access token here:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id={your-app-id}
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

but when I try to make a request for /me/accounts in the GraphAPI I see the error:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "An active access token must be used to query
 information about the current user.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2500,
        "fbtrace_id": "Ab7EmJxQqOjyA5dLz71Cokb"
      }
    }
```

So I think I need to stick to a user access token, but I need to find a permanent one

Comment: There is no permanent token for normal user accounts. System user accounts in a Business Manager setting can have unlimited token though, I think.

Comment: Related with what @CBroe said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906575/facebook-permanent-user-access-token