# Facebook Permanent USER access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I am calling Facebook Ads APIs. I need permanent Facebook USER access token. I have generated a Long lived User Access token already, but it expires after 60 days.
I tried the other articles from Stack overflow, but they all talk about [permanent PAGE access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Can someone tell if it is possible to get Facebook permanent USER access token? If yes, then mention the API that does that task.

Comment: There is no permanent token for normal user accounts. See if you can maybe use a _system user_ for your purposes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way by which we can make the expiry date of normal User Access token permanent
In order to do so, we have to create a system user for the app and generate access token for it. Access token for system users is permanent.

A Normal User Access token has expiry of 60 days as shown below.
[image]
Whereas a System user access token has no expiry date.
[image]

**What is a system user?**

System users represent servers or software making API calls to assets owned or managed by a Business Manager.

Webpage for reference:
[Link1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users)

**How to add a system user?**

Webpage for reference: [Link2](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/503306463479099?id=2190812977867143)

This solution worked for me.

Comment: Hey @Priyanshu Tiwari, I had managed to setup the system user, but I didn't find the way to use it for different business accounts :/ With user access token I've added that user to many business accounts and I was able to read data from API, but I do not see any option to assign/share that user with other businesses.

Comment: Ok, resolved! :) 
- I've added the main business account with system user as a partner, also shared the ad accounts with the partner
- then in main business account updated the system user with access to that ad accounts